# Is it safe to mix calcium carbonate and sodium chloride?

Tags: everyday-chemistry

I know zero about chemistry, and Google has not offered up a plain answer, so I beeseech thee; Is it safe to mix calcium carbonate and sodium chloride to make a simple mouthwash?  Calcium carbonate for the acid neutralizing, and sodium chloride for disinfectant.

Comment: So, salt and chalk?

Comment: Ofc, without any issue. Nothing wud happen

Comment: I cannot even.$%$

Comment: @Jan but you have been beseeched, have you not?!

Comment: @UbaidHassan with a loud buzzing noise.

Answer (score 1):

Safe in context of chemistry, physiology or long term health care prevention ?

With zero knowledge, it is safer to stay with commercial products, until you know, what you are doing.

For mouthwash, calcium carbonate is quite ineffective, being insoluble solid. Better would be solution of sodium bicarbonate ( baking soda ), present in some toothpastes as well.

Salt is not great desinfectant and must be used in really high concentration, that can be very disturbing if swallowed.